# Adding web sockets to my Angular chat app breaks http request (it doesn't fire, but somehow returns old data)

Tags: angular, typescript, http, websocket, socket.io

I'm building a chat app in Angular 17, and I just implemented sockets (socket.io). I have a http request that retrieves messages when the app loads:

```js
getMessages(conversationId: string): Observable<any> {
    const headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this._localStorage.get('accessToken') };
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/messages/' + conversationId + '?skip=0&take=40', { headers });
}
```

And it works when the page loads. After receiving a message through the socket, I just add it to the array of messages. If I then call the method to get all the messages for that conversation, the http request doesn't fire, and somehow it just returns the old data (without the messages received through socket). When I reload the page this request fires and returns all the messages as it's supposed to. This is the method that gets the messages:

```js
getMessagess(conversationId: string) {
    this.subscriptions['getMessages'] = this._appService.getMessages(conversationId)
    .subscribe({
      next: (res) => {        
        this.messages = res;
      },
      error: (err) => {
        this._utilityService.handleError(err, 'getMessages');
      }
    });
}
```

This method is called every time I switch conversations. I know that's not ideal, I will change that in the future, but for now the http request should fire. Why does it return the old data? Does it cache it somwhere? Why does the http request not fire? This only started happening after implementing sockets. If I don't connect to the socket, this request fires every time as it should. Also SSR is enabled.

I tried adding the following headers to disable caching:

```
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
'Pragma': 'no-cache'
```

I tried to disable SSR by adding this to angular.json development and production configurations:

```
"ssr": false,
"prerender": false
```

I tried disabling cache in the browser dev tools (I'm using Chrome).

Comment: Well, when you get messages on page load, I guess you get it from database or somewhere and you set `this.messages = res`, after that you receive new message via socket and you add it to `this.messages`, right? If so, does that new message is saved there from where you get messages on page load? If not, maybe there is a mistake, because when you get messages again if new one is not previously saved, it won't be returned with older messages.

Comment: @MilosStojanovic I send messages over http and they are saved in the database. I receive the message over a socket and add it to the array of messages. I then try to get all the messages over http but the http request doesn't even fire, just somehow returns the old messages, even tho the new messages are saved in the DB. My main question is why does the http request not even fire?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't fire when it returns message?

Comment: I can see it in the network tab in dev tools. The request doesn't appear at all.